# Namespacing and including files in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces, include

I'm using namespaces to structure the files in the project. Now I have a controller-class which lives in a php-file that displays some content to the user. In that php-file another file is included. Somehow the constructed controller in the 'parent'-php-file is not available in the included php-file. This works perfectly fine when not using namespaces, how can this be fixed?

Sample

```
# App\Controllers\UserController.php
namespace App\Controllers

class UserController { 
  public function doSomething() { 
    echo 'Hello..';
  }
}
```

---

```
# Parent.php
use App\Controllers as Controllers;

$userController = new Controllers\UserController();
$userController->doSomething(); // echo's 'Hello..'

include 'Child.php';
```

---

```
# Child.php
$userController->doSomething(); // Call to a member function doSomething on a non-object
```

Comment: I get `Hello..Hello..` when I execute your code in PHP 5.4. What version of PHP are you running? Unless there's something else you're not showing, the code above should work.

Comment: You sure you are not calling `Child.php` directly?

Comment: Thanks for looking with me. I now realize it's because of an ajax-handler which reloads child.php. Never mind :) I'll keep the question open for others who might run in to the same 'issue'.